# Was R. Daneel Olivaw constructed on Earth, and is he alive in the last book of the Foundation series?

Tags: isaac-asimov, foundation

In the Foundation series there is a robot named R. Daneel Olivaw. He helps Hari to be hidden from the Emperor. Is he alive after the Foundation series sequels or prequels? And where was he made? Earth or other planet? If not Earth, then where?

Comment: Which books have you read? This is very clearly answered in the books...

Comment: i couldn't read forward the foundation and the prequels as they are not sold here in our country.

Comment: I was going to say there's always the Book Depository, but it turns out they don't have free shipping to Bangladesh...

Comment: @curiousdannii - while I support your stance in principle, we do have a Meta question about this (can't find the link right now) where consensus was that it's **not** required to know all of any particular canon before asking a question.

Comment: @RacsChisty - What about eBooks? You can always get those as they don't involve snail mail shipping.

Comment: @DarthSatan Sure it's not required, but it's the best way to show research effort! It's one thing if you miss some details in one book or episode, it's another to have never encountered most of the canon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In *The Caves of Steel* R. Daneel Olivaw is introduced, and we are told he was constructed on Earth, but by Auroran scientists.

He is last mentioned in

> *Foundation and Earth*, where he is revealed to be living on the Moon. This is the last book in the internal chronology of the series, but the Foundation prequels were the last to be written.